# Proof that a $2^n . 2^n$ Chessboard with a Missing Square can be covered by L-Shaped Tiles - Missing Step

Tags: proof-explanation, puzzle, tiling

I understand the recursive solution to tiling a $2^n. 2^n$ chessboard with a missing square using L-shaped tiles such as these:

[image]

using the following method to divide the original problem into subproblems:

[image]

However the proof depends on the fact that a chessboard containing $2^n . 2^n - 1$ squares can be covered by the L-shaped tiles. Whereas I can see that the number of squares that in such a defective chessboard is a multiple of $3$, I can't see why it is necessarily the case that all these squares can be covered by the L-shaped tiles, regardless of the position of the missing square.

Can anyone please help me to understand what this is the case?

Comment: Here is a 3D animation of the exact proof that you are looking for: https://youtu.be/GlQCTOG5HqA At the start of the video there is a discreet mathematical proof using a predicate, base case, and induction step, and the remaining 6 minutes goes over the visual intuition for why this must be the case.

Answer (score 1):

This is an inductive proof. The base cases are $n = 0$ which is the first image and $n = 1$ which is the next three images (the case where the missing tile is in the bottom right corner is missing - ah well.) The key to the $n \to n + 1$ step is the last image, but that can be formalized.

In particular, the $n + 1$ case can be reduced to the $n$ case by dividing the board into four quadrants, and placing a single L-shaped tile in the pictured location so as to remove a square from those three quadrants that are not already missing a square.

Each of the four quadrants can then be tiled using the inductive hypothesis.

Comment: So it looks like the divisibility by 3 thing is superfluous. It would be good to know the proof though, for another angle on understanding the puzzle.

Comment: What they have shown is the following:

**(0)** I can tile a $2^0 \cdot 2^0$ chessboard missing a square.

**(1)** I can tile a $2^1 \cdot 2^1$ chessboard missing a square.

**($n \to n + 1$)** I can reduce a $2^{n + 1} \cdot 2^{n + 1}$ chessboard missing a square into four $2^{n} \cdot 2^{n}$ chessboards, each missing a square. Together, this forms a proof.